# Mex C Image Filtering using convolution

Tags: c, matlab, image-processing, mex, imagefilter

Im trying to write a C function that takes in an array of an image and sharpens it by using a sobel filter, and adding the edges back to the original picture, im working with mex inside matlab, the issue seems to be that when i run my function with a 256x256 size image the function works fine, however when i run it with a image that is 512x512 or other sizes, matlab crashes. i know that the problem is in a specific line by debugging, but i cant figure out what that problem is:

The code for the function is show below:

```
void applymaskDouble(int width_image, int height_image, double k ,const double *input, double *output)
{
    k = 1/k;
    double filter[] = {-1,-1,-1,-1,8,-1,-1,-1,-1};
    for (int o =0; o <= 8; o++){
        filter[o] = filter[o]*k;
    }
    int width_filter =3;
    int height_filter =3;
    int offsetx = width_filter/2;
    int offsety = height_filter/2;
    double sum =0;
for(int i = 0; i < width_image; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < height_image; j++)
    {
        int ind = i*height_image + j;
            for(int i2 = 0; i2 < width_filter; i2++)
            for(int j2 = 0; j2 < height_filter; j2++)
            {
                int ind_filter = i2*height_filter + j2;
                int xloc = i-offsetx +i2;
                int yloc = j-offsety + j2;
                int loc = xloc*height_image + yloc;
                if (width_image > (xloc)>=0 && height_image >(yloc)>=0)
                sum = sum + input[loc] * filter[ind_filter]; //problem line

                }
        if(sum > 1)
           sum =1;
        if(sum < 0)
           sum =0;
        output[ind] = sum;
        sum =0;
    }

    for(int i3 = 0; i3 < width_image; i3++)
    for(int j3 = 0; j3 < height_image; j3++)
    {
        int ind2 = i3*height_image + j3;
        output[ind2] = output[ind2] +input[ind2];
}}
```

Comment: What is this line supposed to do? `if (width_image > (xloc)>=0 && height_image >(yloc)>=0)` It certainly does not check if `xloc` and `yloc` lie within those ranges.

Comment: thats what its supposed to do, im trying to ensure that the loc wont go over the boundries.

Comment: Well it does not. You have to check the values independently. `if (width_image > xloc && xloc >= 0 && height_image > yloc && yloc >=0)`

Comment: ive tried that still doesnt work for the bigger images. But thank you.

Comment: OK here is another spot: `loc = xloc*height_image + yloc;` --> `loc = yloc*width_image + xloc;` and possibly similar in other lines.

Comment: thank you! the message before actually made it work, just needed to change some stuff.

Comment: My previous message won't have any effect for a square image. For a rectangular one: read and digest!